# python mss mss.exception.ScreenShotError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-mss

I'm newbie.
I try use mss to screenshot monitor.
My code:

```
for i in range(1, 20000):
  cactus_box = {'left': 508, 'top': 382, 'width': 30, 'height': 33}
  sct = mss()
  sct_img = sct.grab(cactus_box)
```

when i run code, this display error:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mss\windows.py", line 203, in grab
raise ScreenShotError('gdi32.GetDIBits() failed.', locals())
mss.exception.ScreenShotError: ('gdi32.GetDIBits() failed.', {'bits': 0, 'height': 33, 'width': 30, 'gdi': <WinDLL 'gdi32', handle 75f00000 at 0x93dd5f0>, 'monitor': {'left': 508, 'top': 382, 'width': 30, 'height': 33}, 'self': <mss.windows.MSS object at 0x093DD810>})
```

Please, someone can show me solve this error

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this is due to resources not freed. It is fixed in MSS 4.0.0 or newer.

Could you try to use MSS ouside the `for` loop? Something like:

```
with mss() as sct:
    cactus_box = {'left': 508, 'top': 382, 'width': 30, 'height': 33}
    for i in range(1, 20000):
        sct_img = sct.grab(cactus_box)
```

The error message is not very explicit but it tells you that the screenshot is not possible (no bits where retrieved). But we cannot know the cause. A memory error perhaps.

Also, try to print `i` to see if it bugs early.

Comment: Little reminder: [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if the answer is good for you :)